# mPDF set Height for SetHTMLHeader

Tags: height, mpdf

Exist any way to set the Height of header when use SetHTMLHeader function?

In the first page the size by default is correct but in the next pages, the content overwrites the end part of the header.

Regards, Oscar.

Comment: have you set proper values for _margin_header_ & _margin_footer_ while initialising mpdf object `mPDF()` ?

Comment: OK, thanks. Finally use this: $this->mpdf->mPDF('utf-8','A4','','','15','15','28','18'); and now works well. Regards, Oscar.

Comment: You can post your answer and accept it so that someone looking for same thing might find it useful.

Answer (score 10):

Finally use this:

```
$this->mpdf->mPDF('utf-8','A4','','','15','15','28','18');
```

When `15=margin-left`, `15=margin-right`, `28=margin-top`, `18=margin-bottom`

And now works well. 
Regards, Oscar

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE 2019**

Since version 7 parameter set as an array:

```
$mpdfConfig = array(
                'mode' => 'utf-8', 
                'format' => 'A4',
                'margin_header' => 30,     // 30mm not pixel
                'margin_footer' => 10,     // 10mm
                'orientation' => 'P'    
            );
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf($mpdfConfig);
```

**References:**

1. https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/construct.html
2. https://mpdf.github.io/configuration/configuration-v7-x.html