# PHP MPDF. <htmlpageheader> messes up my container data

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, mpdf

Hi I have a problem in my MPDF html to convert in pdf. Here is my code and screenshot below:

HTML

```
<htmlpageheader name="header1">
        my html code here
</htmlpageheader>


<div> my data here... </div>
```

CSS

```
@page {
        header: html_header1; 
    }
```

Screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Your question is duplicated with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637344/mpdf-set-height-for-sethtmlheader

Answer (score 2):

If your header is posted per page, then the header height is ignored according to the manual: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=411

I have worked around this by adding a spacer div to the top of the main body of my HTML:

```
<div style="height: 140px"></div>
```

Not perfect but it works.

If you have headers which apply to all pages, then look at this section of the MPDF config.php file:

```
// If 'pad' margin-top sets fixed distance in mm (padding) between bottom of header and top of text.
// If 'stretch' margin-top sets a minimum distance in mm between top of page and top of text, which expands if header is too large to fit.
$this->setAutoTopMargin = false;
$this->setAutoBottomMargin = false; 
$this->autoMarginPadding = 2;       // distance in mm used as padding if 'stretch' mode is used
```

If setAutoTopMargin is set to false (the default) then your header is also ignored. Try setting it to 'pad' in this case.

Comment: @Alex, if this answer helped you, please mark it as the accepted answer. In the meantime I haven't come up with a better solution myself and I have found that this workaround does indeed do the job. I hope you've found the same, but I could do with the reputation on this site. :-)